# @Configuration annotation causes IllegalArgumentException "is not an enhanced class"

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm rather new to Spring and I'm working with an old 3.2.4.RELEASE version of it inside a Jetty container.  I'm getting a rather odd error when I try to use component-scanner indicating that the @Configuration class I've set up is not an enhanced class:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.datasource.DBConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8a295c55 is not an enhanced class
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setCallbacksHelper(Enhancer.java:621) ~[spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.registerStaticCallbacks(Enhancer.java:594) ~[spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:120) ~[spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:92) ~[spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
... 78 common frames omitted
```

My spring beans file is on the classpath and looks like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.datasource" /></beans>
```

The configuration class that I'm trying to setup looks like the following:

```
@Configuration
public class DBConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataAccessInterface getDataAccessInterface(){
        return new DBDatasource();
    }
}
```

The class that I want to inject the DBDatasource into looks like the following:

```
@Service
public class DBService {

    private DataAccessInterface dai;

    @Autowired
    public DBService(DataAccessInterface dai){
        this.dai = dai;
    }
}
```

What does the exception mean when it says that it is not an enhanced class? Am I not using component scan and the configuration annotation properly?

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml? I suppose that that can be coz of CGLib version conflicts that you use. Also is it OSGi?

Comment: I see org.osgi.core-4.1.0.jar and cglib-nodep-2.2.jar on my classpath however as far as I know we I'm not using OSGI

Answer (score 0):

Please include
`@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example", includeFilters = {@Filter(filterType = ANNOTATION, value = CONFIGURATION)}, excludeFilters = {@Filter(filterType = ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = DBConfiguration)})`